# Shell script to read two columns in CSV and count how many uniq values in Column 2 per each unique value in Column 1

Tags: shell, csv

Shell script to read two columns in CSV and count how many unique values in column two per each unique value in column 1

I have a sheet that looks like

```
1   a
2   a
3   b
3   c
2   a
2   f
2   a
1   d
```

The output I need is this:

```
1 2
2 3
3 2
```

```
cut -f 1,2 | sort | uniq -c | sort
```

I tried the above but I am doing something wrong. New to shell scripting here.

Comment: why `2 3` and not `2 2` ?

Comment: `awk -F '\t' '{!s[$1 FS $2]++ && c[$1]++} END{for(i in c)print i,c[i]}' sheet.tsv`